# How To Use a Local style sheet file with Calyspo Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, reactjs, sass, wp-calypso

I'm trying to learn about the Wordpress Calyspo architecture. I've successfully created their example "Hello World" page using [these instructions](http://calypso.localhost:3000/devdocs/docs/guide/hello-world.md).

Now I'd like to continue past the example and add a style. I've read these [instructions](http://calypso.localhost:3000/devdocs/docs/coding-guidelines/css.md) and created a local **style.scss** file in the same folder as main.jsx per the instructions:

> Take a component called site/index.jsx that renders a site item on the picker. Imagine we are going to set the color for the site title to #333 and change it to #444 when the site is a Jetpack site. Our Sass file will sit alongside site/index.jsx and be called site/style.scss.

The one style in this file is very straightforward:

```
.hello-world__title {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

The element (as rendered in the browser's dev tools) is correct:

```
<h1 class="hello-world__title">Hello, World!</h1>
```

I'm not getting errors from WebPack. When I update the style.scss file, I see messages indicating the public .scss files and .map file have been updated:

```
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /home/rich/dev/projects/wp-calypso/public/editor.css
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /home/rich/dev/projects/wp-calypso/public/style.css
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /home/rich/dev/projects/wp-calypso/public/style-debug.css
Wrote Source Map to /home/rich/dev/projects/wp-calypso/public/styledebug.css.map
```

I see no references to my new style in any of these files.

I wonder if I'm missing a step somewhere, like an entry in a mapping file or something.

BTW - I'm also very new to Reactjs and SASS. I'll happily post any other info that will help solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you missed the last step: import the component's style - file `style.scss` into `assets/stylesheets/_components.scss` then your styles will be generated in `style.css`.

This step is mentioned here: Calypso's [CSS/Sass Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso/blob/master/docs/coding-guidelines/css.md#sass-guidelines)

The answer might be too late and you might already know how to do it now. I just cloned [wp-calypso](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso) yesterday :)